# How to retrieve a file (instead of just its downloadURL) from firebase storage

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire

Maybe this is a stupid question ... but at the moment I just don't know how to get a file (instead of just its downloadURL) from firebase storage.

Using AngularFireStorage (and following the docs: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md) I am just able to get the downloadURL of the file I want:

```
private getBusinessCardFromFirebaseStorage() {

    const ref = this.storage.ref(`${this.idOfUser}/businessCard.card`);
    const url = ref.getDownloadURL();
    //this.file = ???;

}
```

But I need the file (in order to send it to another server ... and I need the file itself ... I cannot send just the url). How can I get the file?

---

UPDATE:

I now tried using the firebase API (instead of AngularFire API). It still doesn't work.

Specifically, I tried the following:

```
 storageRef.child(`${this.idOfUser}/businessCard.card`).getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = function(event) {  
     var blob = xhr.response;
     //the following line does not work ... the external variable is not accessible here:                   
     this.externalVariable = blob; 
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle any errors
});
```

I also tried the following:

```
    var storage = firebase.storage();
    var storageRef = storage.ref();
    var fileRef = storageRef.child(`${this.idOfUser}/businessCard.card`);


    fileRef.getDownloadURL()
        .then(url => {
            //the following line gets never printed:
            console.log('Download URL: ' + url);
            return fetch(url)
        })
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => {
            console.log('File downloaded as blob');
            this.businessNetworkCardFile = new File([blob], 'businessNetworkCard.card', {type: 'application/octet-stream', lastModified: Date.now()});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Something went wrong while downloading the business network card:', error);
        })
```

This didn't work either. 
... It's just ridiculous! How can they make this thing so complicated and so badly documented?!

Comment: You can write a Firebase function that reacts on the new file. [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events)

Comment: Have you followed the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Comment: It's not a stupid question IMHO - I stumbled across the same problem, just can't understand why there isn't a simple way of getting a frigging file from angular storage

Comment: glad to hear I'm not the only one ...

Comment: @Doug Stevenson: I did follow the documentation ... first the documentation for AngularFire, then I followed the docs for firebase ... so far nothing has worked